# iOS switch tab's child view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Is there a way to programmatically switch the view of a certain tab? For example lets say I have a tab bar with 3 tabs. The 3rd tab contains a login/registration flow and when this is complete an account screen should be displayed in the same 3rd tab.

Something along the lines of:

```
if (authenticated) {
    // Set TabBarController tab 3 view to AccountController
} else {
    // Set TabBarController tab 3 view to LoginController
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UITabBarController [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarController/setViewControllers:animated:):

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

With default behaviour like this:

> When you assign a new set of view controllers at runtime, the tab bar controller removes all of the old view controllers before installing the new ones. When changing the view controllers, the tab bar controller remembers the view controller object that was previously selected and attempts to reselect it. If the selected view controller is no longer present, it attempts to select the view controller at the same index in the array as the previous selection. If that index is invalid, it selects the view controller at index 0.

Also, UITabBarController have

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers
```

with the same behaviour, but without animation by default.

In any case, you should recreate all your ViewController's hierarchy. And don't forget that UITabBarController remembers the view controller object that was previously selected and attempts to reselect it or fallback to 0 index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UINavigationController inside the tab, then when registration is completed, just push a new viewController in it.

Comment: This just sets the selected tab, does not change the view controller the tab points to.

Comment: "switch the *view* of a certain tab" not switch to a certain tab